# Netlogo-how to make a turtle turn at a specification?

Tags: netlogo

Please see the below Netlogo file. I want the turtles to turn right at WS3 coming from "buffer storage" and the turtles turn left at WS5 coming from "QC Buffer Storage". However, I am getting an error. I found the attached code online and do not understand it 100%. Could someone please help me?

Thank you so much,
John

```
globals [ 
  IN-free-cabinet 
  IN-free-drum-a
  IN-free-drum-b
  new_directions
  distance-to-jump
  WM-output
  WM-output-bad
  drum-output
  wip
  mlt-aux
  avg-mlt
  ]

patches-own[
  directions
  velocity
  processing-time
  is-processing?
  malfunction
  output
  ID
  bifurcation
]

breed [ machine ]
breed [ drum ]

machine-own [
  birth-time
  death-time
  process-plan
  processing
  time-of-processing
  QC-check
  ]

drum-own [
  birth-time
  process-plan
  processing
  time-of-processing
  ]

to create-WM [ machine-type ]
;********** Create Cabinet **********
 set-default-shape machine "square"
 ask patch -12 0 [
   ifelse count machine-here = 0 [ set IN-free-cabinet TRUE ] [ set IN-free-cabinet FALSE ] 
 ]
 if IN-free-cabinet 
 [
   create-machine 1 [
    setxy -12 0
    set size 1   
    set heading 90
    set color Blue
    set birth-time ticks
    set process-plan ["WS1" "WS2" "WS3" "WS4" "WS5" "WS6" "OUT" ]
    set processing FALSE
    set QC-check "GOOD"
    ] 
 ]
;********** Create Cabinet **********
;********** Create Drums **********
 set-default-shape drum "drum"
 ask patch -7 -3 [
   ifelse count drum-here = 0 [ set IN-free-drum-a TRUE ] [ set IN-free-drum-a FALSE ] 
 ]
  ask patch -3 3 [
   ifelse count drum-here = 0 [ set IN-free-drum-b TRUE ] [ set IN-free-drum-b FALSE ] 
 ]
 if IN-free-drum-a
 [
   create-drum 1 [
    setxy -7 -3
    set size 1   
    set heading 0
    set color Pink
    set birth-time ticks
    set process-plan ["WS3"]
    set processing FALSE
   ]
 ]
  if IN-free-drum-b
 [
   create-drum 1 [
    setxy -3 3
    set size 1   
    set heading 180
    set color Pink
    set birth-time ticks
    set process-plan ["WS5"]
    set processing FALSE
   ]
 ]
;********** Create Drum **********
end

to setup
  ;; (for this model to work with NetLogo's new plotting features,
  ;; __clear-all-and-reset-ticks should be replaced with clear-all at
  ;; the beginning of your setup procedure and reset-ticks at the end
  ;; of the procedure.)
  __clear-all-and-reset-ticks
  set WM-output 0
  set drum-output 0
  set avg-mlt 0
  set mlt-aux 0
  set WM-output-bad 0
;********** Main line **********
  ask patch -11 0 [
    set pcolor White
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1] 
    set velocity 1
    set processing-time WS1-Processing-Time
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set ID "WS1"
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch -10 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch -9 0 [
    set pcolor White
    set directions [-1 90 180 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set processing-time WS2-Processing-Time
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE 
    set ID "WS2"  
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch -8 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch -7 0 [
    set pcolor White
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set processing-time WS3-Processing-Time
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set ID "WS3" 
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch -6 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch -5 0 [
    set pcolor White
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set processing-time WS4-Processing-Time
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set ID "WS4" 
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch -4 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch -3 0 [
    set pcolor White
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set processing-time WS5-Processing-Time
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set ID "WS5" 
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch -2 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch -1 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set processing-time 0
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set ID "WS6" 
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch 0 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 180 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation TRUE
  ]
  ask patch 1 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch 2 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set processing-time 0
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set ID "WS7" 
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch 3 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch 4 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]  
  ask patch 5 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set processing-time 0
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set ID "WS8" 
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch 6 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch 7 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set processing-time 0
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set ID "WS9" 
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch 8 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch 9 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set processing-time 0
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set ID "WS10" 
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]  
  ask patch 10 0 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]
  ask patch 11 0 [
    set pcolor Green
    set directions [-1 -1 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set output TRUE
    set ID "OUT"
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]  
 ;********** Main line **********
 ;********** Drum buffer **********
 ask patch -3 1 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [180 -1 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ] 
  ask patch -3 2 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [180 -1 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ] 
   ask patch -3 3 [
    set pcolor Green
    set directions [180 -1 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]  
  ask patch -7 -1 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [0 -1 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ] 
  ask patch -7 -2 [
    set pcolor Yellow
    set directions [0 -1 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ] 
  ask patch -7 -3 [
    set pcolor Green
    set directions [0 -1 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]  
 ;********** Drum buffer **********
 ;********** Alternative line **********
  ask patch 0 -1 [
    set pcolor Black
    set directions [-1 -1 180 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ] 
  ask patch 0 -2 [
    set pcolor Black
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 2
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]  
  ask patch 1 -2 [
    set pcolor Black
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ] 
  ask patch 2 -2 [
    set pcolor Black
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 2
    set processing-time 20
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set ID "WS11" 
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]   
  ask patch 3 -2 [
    set pcolor Black
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]   
  ask patch 4 -2 [
    set pcolor Black
    set directions [0 -1 -1 -1]
    set velocity 2
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]   
  ask patch 4 -1 [
    set pcolor Black
    set directions [0 -1 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ] 
 ;********** Alternative line **********
 ;********** Line labels **********  
 ask patch -11 1 [
    set plabel "WS1"
  ]
  ask patch -9 1 [
    set plabel "WS2"
  ]
  ask patch -7 1 [
    set plabel "WS3"
  ]
  ask patch -5 1 [
    set plabel "WS4"
  ]
  ask patch -3 1 [
    set plabel "WS5"
    set plabel-color 25
  ]
; ask patch -1 1 [
;    set plabel "WS6"
;  ]
;;  ask patch 2 1 [
;    set plabel "WS7"
;]
;  ask patch 5 1 [
;    set plabel "WS8"
;  ]
;  ask patch 7 1 [
;    set plabel "WS9"
;  ]
;  ask patch 9 1 [
;    set plabel "WS10"
;  ]  
;;  ask patch 2 -1 [
;;    set plabel "WS11"
;;  ]  
  ask patch 11 0 [
    set plabel "OUT"
  ]   
  ask patch -6 0 [
    set plabel "SCANNER"
    set plabel-color 25
  ]
 ;********** Line labels ***********  
 ;********** Input Buffer ***********  
  ask patch -12 0 [
    set pcolor Green
    set directions [-1 90 -1 -1]
    set velocity 1
    set is-processing? FALSE
    set malfunction FALSE
    set bifurcation FALSE
  ]

 ;********** Input Buffer *********** 
end

to execute-random 
;********** Machine movement *********** 
 ask machine [
    ask patch-here[
       set distance-to-jump velocity
       set new_directions remove -1 directions ]
    set heading first new_directions
    ifelse not bifurcation [    
    if not processing and first process-plan != "WS3"[
    if not any? machine-on patch-ahead distance-to-jump and not [malfunction] of patch-ahead distance-to-jump[ jump distance-to-jump ]
    if first process-plan = ID [ 
        set process-plan remove-item 0 process-plan
        set processing TRUE 
        set is-processing? TRUE
        set time-of-processing processing-time
      ]
    ]
      if not processing and first process-plan = "WS3" and [ID] of patch-ahead distance-to-jump = "WS3" and 
;      not [malfunction] of patch-ahead distance-to-jump and 
      not any? machine-on patch-ahead distance-to-jump[
        if any? drum-on patch-ahead distance-to-jump [
          jump distance-to-jump
          set process-plan remove-item 0 process-plan
          set processing TRUE 
          set is-processing? TRUE
          set time-of-processing processing-time
          set shape "WM"
        ]
      ]  
      if not processing and first process-plan = "WS3" and [ID] of patch-ahead distance-to-jump != "WS3" and 
;      not [malfunction] of patch-ahead distance-to-jump and 
      not any? machine-on patch-ahead distance-to-jump[  jump distance-to-jump ]  
 ][ ifelse not any? machine-on patch-ahead distance-to-jump and not [is-processing?] of patch-ahead 2 and not [malfunction] of patch-ahead distance-to-jump [ jump distance-to-jump 
   set process-plan remove-item 0 process-plan
   set process-plan fput "WS7" process-plan
   ][
 if not any? machine-on patch-right-and-ahead 90 2 and ([malfunction] of patch-ahead 2 or any? machine-on patch-ahead 2) [
;   if use-W11 [ 
     set heading 180
    jump 2 
   set process-plan remove-item 0 process-plan
   set process-plan fput "WS11" process-plan ] ] ]
 ]
; ]
;********** Machine movement ***********  
;********** Drum movement *********** 
 ask drum [
   if not processing and [ID] of patch-here != "WS3"[
     ask patch-here[
       set distance-to-jump velocity
       set new_directions remove -1 directions ]
     if not any? drum-on patch-ahead distance-to-jump and ID != "WS3" and not [is-processing?] of patch-ahead distance-to-jump [ jump distance-to-jump ]
     ]
   if  any? machine-on patch-here [ die ]
   ]
;********** Drum movement ***********  
end

to resource-processing
  ask patches [
    if ID = "WS7" [ set processing-time 0 ]
    if ID = "WS11" [ set processing-time 0 ]
    ]

  ask machine [
    if processing [
      set time-of-processing time-of-processing - 1
      ask patch-left-and-ahead 90 1 [ set plabel-color Green]
      ]
    ]
  ask machine [
    if processing [
      if time-of-processing <= 0 [
        ask patch-here [
          set is-processing? FALSE
          ]
        ask patch-left-and-ahead 90 1 [ set plabel-color White]
        set processing FALSE
        if  [ID] of patch-here = "WS5" [ ifelse random-float 1 < 0.1 [ set QC-check "BAD" ] [ set QC-check "GOOD" ] ]
        ]
      ]
    ] 
;   ifelse malfunction-WS7  [ ask patch 2 0 [ set malfunction TRUE ] ]
;   [ ask patch 2 0 [ set malfunction FALSE ] ]
end

to count-output 
  ask machine [
        if plabel = "OUT" [
         set death-time ticks
         ifelse QC-check = "GOOD" [ set WM-output  WM-output + 1 ] [ set WM-output-bad WM-output-bad + 1 ]
         set mlt-aux (mlt-aux + (death-time - birth-time))
         set avg-mlt (mlt-aux / (WM-output + WM-output-bad))
                    die ]
        ]
end

to count-drums
  ask machine [
    if plabel = "SCANNER"
    [set drum-output drum-output + 1]
  ]
  end 

to resource-ocupation
  ask patches [
    ifelse any? machine-here [ set is-processing? TRUE ] [ set is-processing? FALSE ]
    ]

end

to statistics
  set-current-plot-pen "WIP"
  set wip count machine-on patches + count drum-on patches 
  plot wip
  set-current-plot-pen "avg-mlt"
  plot avg-mlt / 10
end

to execute
  create-WM[]
  resource-ocupation
  resource-processing
  execute-random
  tick
  count-drums
  count-output
  statistics
end
```

This is my error message:

```html
REMOVE expected input to be a string or list but got the number 0 instead.
error while patch -3 -1 running REMOVE
  called by procedure EXECUTE-RANDOM
  called by procedure EXECUTE
  called by Button 'Run'

org.nlogo.nvm.ArgumentTypeException: REMOVE expected input to be a string or list but got the number 0 instead.
 at org.nlogo.prim.etc._remove.report(_remove.java:57)
 at org.nlogo.prim._asm_procedureexecuterandom_setobservervariable_61.perform()
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.runExclusive(Context.java:119)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.ExclusiveJob.run(ExclusiveJob.java:57)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.runExclusiveJob(Context.java:162)
 at org.nlogo.prim._asm_procedureexecuterandom_ask_59.perform(:1)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.runExclusive(Context.java:119)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.ExclusiveJob.run(ExclusiveJob.java:57)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.runExclusiveJob(Context.java:162)
 at org.nlogo.prim._asm_procedureexecuterandom_ask_57.perform(:1)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.stepConcurrent(Context.java:91)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.ConcurrentJob.step(ConcurrentJob.java:82)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.org$nlogo$job$JobThread$$runPrimaryJobs(JobThread.scala:143)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobThread.scala:78)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76)
 at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:88)
 at org.nlogo.util.Exceptions$.handling(Exceptions.scala:41)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run(JobThread.scala:75)

NetLogo 5.2.0
main: org.nlogo.app.AppFrame
thread: JobThread
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_51 (Oracle Corporation; 1.8.0_51-b16)
operating system: Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (amd64 processor)
Scala version 2.9.2
JOGL: (3D View not initialized)
OpenGL Graphics: (3D View not initialized)
model: headsline

06:45:24.666 SwitchedTabsEvent (org.nlogo.app.Tabs) AWT-EventQueue-0
06:45:24.661 RuntimeErrorEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
06:45:24.659 JobRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) JobThread
06:45:24.657 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2 (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0
06:45:24.657 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2 (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0
06:45:24.657 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2 (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0
06:45:24.657 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2 (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0
06:45:24.657 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2 (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0
06:45:24.657 PeriodicUpdateEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
06:45:24.549 AddJobEvent (org.nlogo.window.ButtonWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
```

Comment: This code is too extensive to understand without the actual mode, perhaps you could upload the .nlogo file and share it so that we can see what's going on. Also, describe what  WS3 and WS5 means for you, personally I don't understand a bit of the problem you've got.

Answer (score 1):

J.Chen, I don't have an answer to the question you asked, but the help that you really need is about how to start debugging a NetLogo Program.  David Merino is right that we don't have enough information to debug the program for you, but you should take more steps first.  StackOverflow is not a "debug my program" site.  It's a site for questions that you have after you've tried to work through the problem and can't find a solution.  At that point you can post a more specific question.

Here are some tips for debugging the program you're experimenting with:

The error message begins:

```
REMOVE expected input to be a string or list but got the number 0 instead.
error while patch -3 -1 running REMOVE
  called by procedure EXECUTE-RANDOM
  called by procedure EXECUTE
  called by Button 'Run'
```

That means that the error is caused by an instance of the `remove` function.  In NetLogo, you can use the Find command on the Edit menu to search for "remove".  Better yet, search for "remove ", i.e. with a space after it.  There are two instances of the `remove` command in the program, so you know that one of them is causing the problem.

Next, the error message tells you that the `remove` function was called by the procedure `execute-random`.  This is going to be a user-defined procedure.  Its definition will start with `to execute-random`.  It turns out that both instances of `remove` are in the `execute-random` procedure, so you now have to figure out which one is causing the problem.  If one of the `remove`s was in `execute-random`, and the other wasn't, you could ignore the other one for now.

Now, the error message says that "REMOVE expected input to be a string or list but got the number 0 instead."  If you look at the documentation for `remove` in the NetLogo dictionary, you see that its second argument is supposed to be a list or a string.  The `remove` commands in the source code both try to remove the number `-1` from something called `directions`.  Since -1 is not a character that could be in a string, `directions` is probably supposed to be a list.  However, the error message tells you that sometimes, `direction` contains the number 0 instead of a list.

What I would do at this point, probably, is to insert a `print directions` statement into the source code just before the line containing `remove`.  It might also be useful to add `print self` to print out the patch.  I'm not sure what to do next, because I don't understand the program, and I can't run it without the GUI elements.

However, here is one tip that's not at all obvious: All variables start out with the value 0.  `directions` is defined near the top of the source code as a `patches-own` variable.  What I suspect is that for at least one patch, this variable is not getting initialized to have a list as its value before one of the `remove` lines is executed, and that that's why `directions` has the value 0.